# Github Gists - Download Gist as Image File for Code Report

Tags: github, png, gist

I have some pretty huge SQL queries as github gists and I would like to download them as images (eg PNG) in order to put them in a Word report document.

I cannot find a way to do that, they just download as .sql files.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What is the gist url?

Comment: Sorry, I am obligated to keep the code private, so it's a secret gist. I cannot share the URL. Could you just tell me hot to do it myself? You could use any open gist as an example URL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An similar example would be useful.

Comment: How about this [example](https://gist.github.com/d867ad4ed3abfd0d3b43.git)

Comment: Ah, wait. Do you want to download your gist as image? Why don't you put the code directly in your document?

Comment: Well, I tried that too, but I'm not satisfied by how it looks.

Comment: Well, this question is not about programming. You may want to ask this on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Well, no problem, but you could tell me that before asking for code and suggesting something obvious. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I agree, but first it wasn't clear for me what you're trying to do. You're welcome.

Comment: If what you want fits on your screen, you can capture your screen into a PNG.  For example, open another small terminal screen and use ImageMagick's "import gist.png", click corner of the area you want to capture, then click the opposite corner.  Or use your own favorite screen capture method.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.

I use a Firefox extension (FireShot) that can take screenshots of pages that dont fit the screen, while cropping the exact part that you need.

I am sorry that as it turned out, it wasn't about programming after all, although I'm pretty sure there must be a way to do this programmatically.
(FireShot is a program after all...)